# Technical Features of server to hold Quantum GIS, GeoServer and GeoNetwork

Tags: server

I work at my company as Project Assistance and we think of migrating of ArcGIS to another open source program similar to ArcGIS like Quantum GIS, GeoServer and GeoNetwork and I need to know the technical characteristics of a server to do this and buy one. These tools let me to publish maps, to process maps, I guess. I want to know which are technical specifications that a server needs to support the job of these packages (QGIS, GeoServer and GeoNetwork) for example, recommended memory for 40 or 50 users working with maps to they don't have any problem with their jobs, about storage space of 40 terabytes or more, etc.

I want for 40 or 50 users publishing maps, processing maps, sharing data, availability in disk such as mirror, storage space for maps 40 or more terabytes, memory I don't know, how many do you suggest me? of which depends on the size of the maps?

I am not restricted in budget, the important is that server was high performance and it was dedicated and centralized all maps, actually everybody makes his map and it's a problem.

It's for a project to national level for disasters, earthquakes, etc.

I'm sorry for my writing in English. I speak Spanish.

I'm new and I can't answer my post until tomorrow so I edit my first post.

---

On http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap says:

"El conjunto de servidores consta de un servidor de base de datos de gran rendimiento, un servidor de aplicaciones para el sitio web, tres servidores de aplicaciones para la API y un servidor destinado al renderizado del mapa"

Do I also need an application server and another application server for rendering map?

application server (GeoServer?)
application server for rendering map (Geonetwork?)
application server for API ?????? for example, what application?

---

That is I don't know. "renderizado del mapa"

Comment: do you have a budget?

Comment: could you spend all the licence savings?

Comment: I want for 40 or 50 users publishing maps, processing maps, availability in disk such as mirror, storage space for maps 40 or more terabytes, memory I don't know, how many do you suggest me? of which depends on the size of the maps?

I am not restricted in budget, the important is that server was high performance and it was dedicated and centralized all maps, actually everybody makes his map and it's a problem. 

It's for a project to national level for disasters, earthquakes, etc.

I'm sorry for my writing in English. I speak Spanish.

Comment: I have understand that Quantum GIS, Geoserver and Geonetwork are open source, and they use PostGIS that is openSource, and WebServer Apache is opensource too. I only have to spend in hardware nor in software.

Answer (score 2):

I think OpenStreetMaps is a good reference about server configuration for geographic applications using postgresql and geoserver. It serves [1.5 billion nodes](http://www.openstreetmap.org/stats/data_stats.html) (points with data), it's world wide data and has thousands of users editing.

[In this page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Servers#UCL_-_In_Use) you can check the different servers configuration they have, those are very powerful and expensive computers.

About your case, my opinion is:
Start with a good commodity hardware like an i7 12GB RAM 1TB of disk. Than you can expand the disk if you need.

What is essential:
Good management of the data: For example, one should remove the junk created in sub steps of processing.
Software tuning: For example If you install postgresql and then do nothing, it won't use all the computer capacity, you have to configure it.